# Exception while calling WCF method in Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, binding, duplex

i have an unsual issue and so far Google hasn't been any help at all.

I have setup a DUPLEX client connection to a WCF Server using WSDualHttpBinding, this works fine. I then placed the client connection in a thread and now i receive this exception (Message, Stack, InnerException):

> the thread was being aborted. bei
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElement..ctor()  [14948]
>   bei
>   System.ServiceModel.MessageSecurityOverHttp.CreateSecurityBindingElement(Boolean
>   isSecureTransportMode, Boolean isReliableSession,
>   MessageSecurityVersion version)  [14948]    bei
>   System.ServiceModel.WSDualHttpBinding.CreateBindingElements()  [14948]
>   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.EnsureInvariants(String
>   contractName)  [14948]    bei
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.BuildChannelFactory(ServiceEndpoint
>   serviceEndpoint, Boolean useActiveAutoClose)  [14948]    bei
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnOpening()  [14948]    bei
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)  [14948]    bei
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.EnsureOpened()  [14948]    bei
>   System.ServiceModel.DuplexChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel(InstanceContext
>   callbackInstance, EndpointAddress address, Uri via)  [14948]    bei
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannel()  [14948]    bei
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelInternal()  [14948]
>
>   bei System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.get_Channel()

The class method that sets up the connection and calls the method is called as follows:

```
await Task.Run(() => new ClientConnector().LoadIT());
```

The setup is as follows (in the LoadIT method):

```
 try
            {
                var FXDuplexCallback = new FXDuplexCallback();
                FXDuplexCallback.ServiceCallbackEvent += HandleServiceCallbackEvent;

                var instanceContext = new InstanceContext(FXDuplexCallback);
                var dualHttpBinding = new WSDualHttpBinding();

                dualHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
                dualHttpBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
                dualHttpBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 00, 03);
                dualHttpBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

                var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(sServiceEndpointUri);
                oProxy = new FXDuplexProxy(instanceContext, dualHttpBinding, endpointAddress);

                //Start client connection with OpenTF and receive current user data.
                oRoomData = oProxy.FXClientConnect();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("e.Message + e.StackTrace + e.InnerException);
                oProxy.Abort();
            }
```

FXDuplexProxy is the class which inherits from DuplexClientBase<*the server contract interface*>

I have no idea why this exception only happens while i run the conneciton in a thread, does anyone have any ideas?